# how to make a link click show content of div using z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make a anchor link click should show the content of a div but without pushing the content underneath the link down.And when you click out side of that div should close the div.

Javascript or jquery is fine. Here is what I got so far:

```
<a onclick="toggleDiv()"></a>
<div id="translate" style="display:none;">This is the content should be shown but don't push the content down.</div>
```

Here is the script

```
function toggleDiv()
    {
        var googleDiv = document.getElementById('translate');
        if(googleDiv.style.display == 'block')
            googleDiv.style.display = 'none';
        else
          googleDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with z-index.

Comment: Then how to make it so that content will not be pushed down

Answer (score 0):

Try using `visibility` instead of `display`.

`style="visibility:hidden;"`

```
if(googleDiv.style.visibility == 'visible')
  googleDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
else
  googleDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: You need to change your else block to use `googleDiv.style.visibility`

Comment: But how do you make div hidden when you click outside of the div and not on the link?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `query`. If you using it:

```
<a onclick="$('#translate').toggle()"></a>
```